# Values that are not inside XML being imported improperly

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import links that are inside a map that I'm specifying in detail in the formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(
           "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9",
           "//tr[@class='rowLive']//td[@scope='col']//a/@href"
          )
```

The links I'm looking for are at this location on the page:

[image]

The expected result would be this:

[image]

But for some reason I can't understand, the result is being this:

[image]

**I would like help to understand what is going on and how I should map the XML correctly so that these values no longer appear.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(IMPORTXML("http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9",
 "//tr[@class='rowLive']//td[@scope='col']//a/@href"), 
 ISURL(IMPORTXML("http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9",
 "//tr[@class='rowLive']//td[@scope='col']//a/@href"))))
```

[image]